# Access multiple dimension of an array ("mixed indexing") in a single call?

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing

Given the following array: `samples * rows * columns`

```py
arr_3d = np.array([
    [
        [ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]
    ],
    [
        [10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],
    [
        [19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27]
    ]
])
```

This works, but can I access rows and columns in the same `[_,_,_]` call?

```py
>>> arr_3d[[1,2],:,:][:,:,[0,1]]

array([
    [
        [10, 11],
        [13, 14],
        [16, 17]
    ],
    [
        [19, 20],
        [22, 23],
        [25, 26]
    ]
])
```

This does not behave as expected:

```py
>>> arr_3d[[1,2],:,[0,1]]


array([
    [10, 13, 16],
    [20, 23, 26]
])
```

---

UPDATE: looks like this is a known challenge of *mixed indexing*

> https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0021-advanced-indexing.html#mixed-indexing

Comment: Related from the [documentations](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0021-advanced-indexing.html#mixed-indexing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
arr_3d[np.ix_([1,2], np.arange(arr_3d.shape[1]), [0,1])]
```

output:

```
array([[[10, 11],
        [13, 14],
        [16, 17]],

       [[19, 20],
        [22, 23],
        [25, 26]]])
```

Comment: sorry, I should have included `[0,1]` not `[0]` as the column accessor in my original question to be more true to the intent

Comment: @Kalanos I see, let me update